# Multiple PHP version on CentOS 7 still using the default

Tags: php, centos7, fpm

I am trying to setup my server (centos7) to have multiple php versions and found this [guide](https://www.tuxtips.net/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-with-apache-on-centos-7-linux/) on google. Everything works except that the website I am trying to run with php8.2 still using the default which is php7.1.

Is there anything that I missed looking? Or any command that I can use to troubleshoot?

**Check list**

*PHP-FPM*

- `sudo systemctl status php71-php-fpm` - good and running @ port 9071
- `sudo systemctl status php82-php-fpm` - good and running @ port 9082

*Virtual Host*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /DATA1/www/php82-custom.com>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
    ServerName php82-custom.com
    DocumentRoot /DATA1/www/php82-custom.com
    DirectoryIndex info.php
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9082"
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
    Action php82-fcgi /cgi-bin/php82.fcgi
    ErrorLog /DATA1/www/log/php82-custom.com
    CustomLog /DATA1/www/log/php82-custom.com-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

[image]

Comment: from what I can see, the SetHandler should be something like: `SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9082"`

Comment: @hassan Hi. Still not working. I don't know why it still using the default php version after configuring with no errors.

Comment: the silly question, are you sure that you restarted your apache server?

Comment: @hassan Yes. Even the fpms too.

Comment: Stop php71, will the site still work?

Comment: And check the contents of these start scripts, most likely they are the same by default.

Comment: @hassan yes, stopping php71-php-fpm still showing the 7.1.33 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SetHandler` directive is a `Directory || Location` scoped directive.

You will need to move it inside your directory directive:

> ### SetHandler Directive
>
> When placed into an .htaccess file or a  or  section, this directive forces all matching files to be parsed through the handler given by handler-name

In your case, you need to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /DATA1/www/php82-custom.com>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9082"
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
    ServerName php82-custom.com
    DocumentRoot /DATA1/www/php82-custom.com
    DirectoryIndex info.php
    ErrorLog /DATA1/www/log/php82-custom.com
    CustomLog /DATA1/www/log/php82-custom.com-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm getting error "Service Unavailable" The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

I also tried restarting all services: httpd, fpms.

Comment: what is the apache2 error log?

Comment: I used this line instead and it is working now: SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9082"

Thank you.